# What is the bridge between the following diagrams of Browser Engine and JS Runtime?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, v8, event-loop

I have been reading about how does the browser works and what are the components of a browser. I came across various articles on how does the browser parse JS and rendering process etc, but I was not able to MERGE these two diagrams which I found in almost every other article. Where does the WebAPI, Callback Queue, Eventloop etc sit in the first figure ? Is the Javascript Engine and Javascript Intepreter same in both the diagrams ?

If someone can help me with the following:

1. Merge these two diagrams and provide with a new diagram adding web APIs, eventloop etc in the overall picture
2. Also it would be awesome if you could give an example of each of the following:
   [image]

[image]

Comment: Both diagrams do not make sense at all. You should really get better sources.

Comment: https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/

Answer (score 0):

In short, the second diagram provides some detail on what's inside the box labeled "JavaScript Interpreter" in the first diagram (which uses that term as a synonym of "JS engine"), while the implementations of "Web APIs" are part of the rendering engine.

That said, as @JonasWilms points out, the overall accuracy/quality of both of these diagrams is quite debatable, to say the least. One example of an inaccuracy is the second diagram's claim that the DOM is part of the JS engine.

Comment: Regarding the *DOM "inaccuracy"*, I note that nothing on the right side of that diagram is part of the JS engine, so I wonder if it's not a bad design that makes us all *misread* the diagram, rather than an issue with the diagram's author's comprehension. I believe the "JS engine" label only concerns the left rectangle. Both "Web APIs" and "Callback Queue"  would not be part of it. Though that just further cement the "debatable quality" point.